# How Do i read the Lake database in Azure Synapse in a PySpark notebook

Tags: pyspark, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

Hi I created a Database in Azure Synapse Studio and I can see the database and table in there, Now I have created a Notebook where I have added the required libraries but I am unable to read the table by below code. Can anyone fix what wrong am i doing here ?

My database name is **Utilities_66_Demo** . It gives me error as

> AnalysisException: Path does not exist:
> abfss://users@stcdmsynapsedev01.dfs.core.windows.net/Utilities_66_Demo.parquet

From where should I take the path? I tried to follow the MS [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started-analyze-spark). Where Do I read path? if I click on edit Database, i get this

[image]

```
%%pyspark
df = spark.read.load('abfss://users@stcdmsynapsedev01.dfs.core.windows.net/Utilities_66_Demo.parquet', format='parquet')
display(df.limit(10))
```

Trying to access the created Lake Database Table:
Selected Azure Synapse Analytics:

[image]

I select my workspace and in dropdown there is no table shown:

[image]

> I select Edit and put my Db name and Table name and it says Invalid
> details.

**Now I select Azure Dedicated Synapse Pool from Linked Service**,

I get no option to select in SQL Pool or Table, and without SQL Pool I am unable to create a Linked service just by inserting Table name:

[image]

Comment: If it is a Lake Database in your default ADLS account, you should just be able to reference the "databasename.tablename" in your Spark queries.

Comment: can you write the query here or refrence me to link. i would like to use Pyspark here

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

You can directly go to your ADLS and right click the parquet file and select properties. There, you will be able to find the ABFSS path which is in the format :
**abfss://<container_name>@<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path**

[image]

Comment: Please follow this step and let me know how do we find the ABFSS path:

go to Synapse Workspace and click on Data--> Add a Lake database, create a database and a Table and add some column. You will now have a table inside a Database in Lake database in the workspace tab inside the Synpase workspace. There is no data in it and there is just table with columns. How do you write any data in this table?

Comment: What you have is an external table created with ADLS as source, you would have to go to tab `Develop` -> `SQL Script` to interact with the table. You have probably used the inbuilt serverless pool database to create this table on

Comment: refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/database-designer/modify-lake-database  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/load-data-overview#4-load-the-data-into-dedicated-sql-pool-staging-tables-using-polybase

Comment: you are right here, the article do not have anything as how we insert data in the table created. can you provide any refrence link for creating data in the table created

Comment: i created the notebook from this serverless table and in there I created a dtaframe with some data, now how do i insert it in this serverless table created

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9OrV.png

Comment: Check the above snip